# focus works on IE and Firefox but fail in Chrome

Tags: javascript

I have this code to place focus on an element (textbox). That works fine in IE and Firefox, but in chrome, not work :/

I'm using JS without jQuery (Mandatory for the project) and VB.NET

Suggestions? :)

Thx

```
        var elem = document.getElementById("<%=txtPesquisa.ClientID%>");
        var elemLen = elem.value.length;
        // For IE Only
        if (document.selection) {
            // Set focus
            elem.focus();
            // Use IE Ranges
            var oSel = document.selection.createRange();
            // Reset position to 0 & then set at end
            oSel.moveStart('character', -elemLen);
            oSel.moveStart('character', elemLen);
            oSel.moveEnd('character', 0);
            oSel.select();
        }
        else if (elem.selectionStart || elem.selectionStart == '0') {
            // Firefox/Chrome
            elem.selectionStart = elemLen;
            elem.selectionEnd = elemLen;
            elem.focus();
        }
```

Comment: And you're sure it's `focus()` and not the selection stuff that is failing in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to select text in the input box I think you meant `elem.selectionStart = 0` instead of `elem.selectionStart = elemLen;`

**Demo http://jsfiddle.net/ygalanter/fmP64/1/**

But the focus works in your code as it is and the original code places cursor at the end of the text

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

The problem wasn't in this function, but elsewhere in the code.

However, I made a slight change to the code be perfect and put the autofocus at the end of the word:

```
        var elem = document.getElementById("<%=txtPesquisa.ClientID%>");
        var elemLen = elem.value.length;
        // For IE Only
        if (document.selection) {
            // Set focus
            elem.focus();
            // Use IE Ranges
            var oSel = document.selection.createRange();
            // Reset position to 0 & then set at end
            oSel.moveStart('character', elemLen);
            oSel.moveStart('character', elemLen);
            oSel.moveEnd('character', elemLen);
        }
        else if (elem.selectionStart || elem.selectionStart == '0') {
            // Firefox/Chrome
            elem.selectionStart = elemLen;
            elem.selectionEnd = elemLen;
            elem.focus();
        }
```

Thx for the help :)